# Custom Messages including variables in global field?

Tags: plugin-development, emails, globals

Is it possible to setup messages (for transactional emails) as global text fields that include variables such as {{ firstName }}, {{ lastName }}, {{ email }} etc.?

For example:

- Custom plugin fires off transactional email
- Email copy is pulled from global text field
- Variables like {{ firstName }} are substituted from plugin action
- Email is sent

Comment: I'm probably mis-understanding something, but a plugin has access to all custom fields/globals and would be able to compose the email with whatever content is needs.

Comment: @BradBell just looking for a way to make the emails customizable by an admin via a text field. For example someone could change Dear {{ firstName }}, click here to sign up to Dear {{ fistName }}, thanks for signing up.

Comment: Actually @BradBell I just ran across messages under email settings. Is there a way to extend that functionality?